# MockMvc: Cannot resolve print method in andDo(print())

Tags: java, junit, spring-test, mockmvc

I'm new to JUnit testing.  I'm now trying to test a Spring endpoint using [`MockMvc`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.9/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/MockMvc.html), but the `andDo(print())` method can not be found.
Are there any things I have to import in order to use this or what?

```
  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Test
  public void compareDeleteTest() throws Exception{
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.add("Content-Type", "application/json");

    RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.delete("api/compare/3")
            .headers(httpHeaders);

    MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder)
            .andDo(print());
}
```

Here's what shown in my IDE:

[image: IDE screenshot with error: "Cannot resolve method 'print()'"]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the `print()` you are looking for is in `MockMvcResultHandlers`

Here is how you can do it -

```
ResultActions resultActions = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder)
                                     .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print());
```

Comment: Hi, I get only partial output and then "(truncated)...". How can I make sure the complete json is printed without truncation?

Answer (score 8):

Use Java's static imports to be able to call it without class name or any object:

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;
```